# XSD Schemas allowing special/reserved characters in string element tag

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd

In a string element tag the XML parser will get *confused* if it finds the following characters

'
"
<
>

&

(i.e. lets say the name of company has been retrieved from a database field, and it looks like this: "Smith & Sons")

The question is - how can you design your XSD to ignore these characters if found within an element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make it ignore these characters.

They are *invalid* in XML and therefore need to be escaped or wrapped in CDATA sections. There is no way for these characters to show up in XML *unless* you build the XML using improper means (namely: string concatenation).

If you build your XML using proper means (an XML library of some sorts) these characters are replaced by their XML-escaped counterparts transparently and no parser will complain.

Comment: Wait, single and double quotes are invalid characters in XML?

Comment: @MarkElliot Well, yes - depending on the situation. They are invalid in attribute values that use them as delimiters. So `attribute='...&apos;...'` is well-formed, so is `attribute="...&quot;..."`.  In other places the literal single and double quotes are allowed. So no, they are not strictly forbidden, but they cannot be ignored either (which was the OP's question).

Comment: Got it, but, for instance, it is valid to say `attribute="...'..."`, as well as `attribute='..."...'`, which is fairly common practice (and something I've been doing so long that it was surprising to read this)

Comment: @MarkElliot Right, this works. But this is also the reason why there are two native escape sequences for single and double quotes. Occasionally you have both types in the same attribute value, so you have to escape one type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you dont.

The creator of the XML content should place them in CDATA sections.

Answer (score 1):

If you extract "Smith & Sons" from the database, it should be escaped when inserted into your XML

e.g. the above will become 'Smith &amp; Sons'

Similarly for the other characters above.

How this happens depends on how you build your XML content. If using an API such as DOM, then this should happen automatically. If you're assembling your XML by hand, then you have to worry about this (and other issues like character encoding - which means using an API is the preferable option here).